# Azure B2C: Custom claim isn't written into AAD via custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

It seems that I've hit a road block when it comes to writing custom claims to Azure Active Directory (AAD).  I'm trying to write the organization into ADD, but it appears that when I query the users via Graph API, I don't see any trace of the organization data.  I'm wondering if there's something off with how I attempted to write the data or there's a techincal detail that I'm not aware of that can cause this issue?

Here's the custom claim that I want to save to AAD.

```xml
      <ClaimType Id="extension_organization">
        <DisplayName>Organization Name</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Name of admin's organization.</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
```

And here is where I'm writing the claims (it's pretty much what you would see in the examples):

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" /> 
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password"/>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="unknown" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration" />
  
            <!-- Optional claims. -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_organization" /> 
          </PersistedClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

On an interesting note, it seems that not even the e-mail can be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying the Graph API for custom/extension attributes, you will need to make sure you `select` the extension attributes with the following syntax:

**extension_{b2cExtensionsAppId}_organization**

Where `{b2cExtensionsAppId}` is the Application/Client ID for the application in your B2C tenant that is automatically generated:

`b2c-extensions-app. Do not modify. Used by AADB2C for storing user data.`

*Edit* - Remove the dashes (-) from the Extensions Application/Client ID

`79af1ae0-cacb-401a-9a42-1f2178adc0ef` gets converted to `79af1ae0cacb401a9a421f2178adc0ef`.

Example:
`b2c_79af1ae0cacb401a9a421f2178adc0ef_organization`

Comment: Attempting to query for the extension attribute yields the following error: ```Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Term 'extension_{b2cExtensionsAppId}_organization' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression.```

Comment: You'll need to replace `{b2cExtensionsAppId}` with the Application/Client ID (GUID) in your B2C tenant.

To locate from the Azure B2C Portal, select `App Registrations` and then choose `All Applications`. In there you will find the automatically generated application labeled `b2c-extensions-app. Do not modify. Used by AADB2C for storing user data.` - Open that and collect the `Application (client) ID` value.

Comment: I know that.  I just removed the actual AppID to show the error message when I attempt to query for this attribute.  Isn't Application/Client ID sensitive information?

Comment: Nevermind.  Apparently, you can't have hypens within the ```{b2cExtensionsAppId}```

Comment: @JosephWoolf - I've updated the original answer to make note of that with an example.